# Proper way to do multicolumn clickable lists in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

It seems that using the grid with .list-group-item in Bootstrap 4 doesn't work any more (the items don't display on the same row). What is the proper way to create a clickable, multi-column list in Boostrap 4? I've just about managed to create a nicely formatted list with div and .row and .col-* - but in order to add clickable on hover, some more CSS is required. Is there a simpler, more elegant way of achieving this in Bootstrap 4?

This is what I have so far (but the text is blue):

```
<a href="#">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">Date</div>
        <div class="col-2">Type</div>
        <div class="col-8">Content</div>
    </div>
</a>
```

And this doesn't work in Bootstrap 4 (but it must have worked in Bootstrap 3, as there seem to be plenty of examples about):

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item row">
        <div class="col-2">Date</div>
        <div class="col-2">Type</div>
        <div class="col-8">Content</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The official docs for Bootstrap 4 have mainly single column examples of list-group, with only one example of two columns aligned using d-flex. But as far as I can tell, proper grid style alignment can't be achieved for multiple columns using d-flex.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue, one approach is to add classes "row row-cols-2 flex-row" to the ul.list-group element.  You can try other values instead of 2 and use the screen size classes too.  I think in your case "flex-row" is the class you need the most.